# Validating an obfuscation token

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, penetration-testing, websecurity

I am building a secured algorithm to get rid of obfuscation attacks. The user is validated with the token which should satisfy following condition:

1. username in lowercase letters only and username is at least 5 digit long.
2. username is followed with #.
3. After # first two characters are important. A digit and a character always. This part contains at least a digit, a lowercase and an upperCase Letter.
4. In between there could be any number of digits or letters only.
5. In the last the digit and character should exactly match point-3's digit and character.
6. It should end with #.
7. The characters in the middle of two # should be at least 5 characters long.
8. The complete token consists only of two #, lowercase and uppercase letters and digits. And

I don't know about regular expression but my guide told me this task is easily achieved at validation time by regular expressions. After I looked for long on the internet and found some links which are similar and tried to combine them and got this:

`^[a-z]{5,}#[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]*[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}#$`

But this only matches 1 test case. I don't know how I can achieve the middle part of two hashes. I tried to explain my problem as per my english. Please help.

Below test cases should pass

`userabcd#4a39A234a#`

`randomuser#4A39a234A#`

`abcduser#2Aa39232A#`

`abcdxyz#1q39A231q#`

`randzzs#1aB1a#`

Below test cases should fail:

`randuser#1aaa1a#`

`randuser#1112#`

`randuser#a1a1##`

`randuser#1aa#`

`u#4a39a234a#`

`userstre#1qqeqe123231q$`

`user#1239a23$a#`

`useabcd#4a39a234a#12`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
 ^[a-z]{5,}#(?=[^a-z\n]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z])(\d[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]*\1#$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the line respectively.
- **`[a-z]{5,}`** - Matches lower case user names 5 or more times.
- **`#`** - Matches `#` literally.
- **`(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])`** - Represents a positive look-ahead asserting at least a lowercase letters.
- **`(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])`** - Represents a positive look-ahead asserting at least an uppercase letters.
- **`(\d[a-zA-Z])`** - Represents a capturing group matching first 2 character i.e. a digit and a letter. If you want other way then use `[a-zA-Z]\d`.
- **`[a-zA-Z\d]*`** - Matching zero or more of the characters in mentioned character set.
- **`\1`** - Represents back-reference exactly matching the captured group.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/inHIRq/4)

**Note:** If you want to match one string at a time i.e. for practical purposes; remove `\n` from the character sets.

---

You can use this regex as an alternative.

```
^[a-z]{5,}#(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(\d[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]*\1#$
```

**Recommended reading:** [**Principle of contrast**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast)

Comment: Not sure if OP added [tag:language-agnostic] tag deliberately, but this regular expression is not language-agnostic. Not all regex flavors support lookaheads, or character class shortcuts such as `\d`.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I'm not even sure if it's possible to write a portable regex for this. `^[a-z]{5,}#(([0-9][A-Z])[0-9A-Z]*[a-z][0-9A-Za-z]*|([0-9][a-z])[0-9a-z]*[A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]*)(\2|\3)#$` is a working POSIX ERE, but I didn't test it with other regex flavors.